# How do tiny humanoids not fall over?

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, humanoid

Gravity is around 9.8m/s^2 on Earth. Unfortunately, this figure means different things at different scales. We could put this figure in terms of height (1.6m) and reaction times (0.2s), which shoul give us a value of about 0.25 h/r^2. However, if we try and calculate the value for a smaller being, then you'll find that the effects of gravity measured by these units is increased, specifically by the inverse of the scale factor. For example, let's look at a being 1/12 the scale of a regular human. Their height (and therefore h/r^2) is 1/12 the value of a regular human, and so gravity pulls at a rate of 3 h/r^2, 12 times larger than for a regular sized human (assuming the same reaction time)

While smaller beings would certainly be better at holding up against the stronger-seeming gravity, they would have far less time (specifically the time is divided by the square root of the inverse of their scale factor) to react to any perturbations that might knock them over

What adaptations would best help a tiny humanoid avoid falling over? The humanoid should still be bipedal and upright, and preferably should still resemble a human as much as possible

Comment: I honestly have trouble understanding what exactly you are asking about. Could you please provide some definitions of the formulae and units used? 

m = meters, s= seconds, but I am unfamiliar with h and r. h might refer to Planck constant but I have no worldly idea about r.

Comment: @Bartors 'h' is the specific humanoid's height, and 'r' is their reaction time. It's a unit of acceleration relative to each species

Comment: You have at least one fundamental error: the assumption that reaction times will stay the same.  Reation times depend on neural propagation time.  Smaller creatures have shorter nerve pathways, thus their reaction times are quicker, all else being equal.  Observe any small animal, such as mice or squirrels, or how many small birds (quail, roadrunners, &c) are able to walk and run without falling.

Comment: Reaction time is really the height of the animal divided by the speed of signal propagation along neuron axons; in humans it is about 0.2 seconds from eye to foot because on our high-speed neurons the signal propagates at about 10 meters/second. (Reaction time is only about 0.1 seconds from eye to hand, because shorter distance.) With the same kind of neurons, a humanoid 1/12 the height of a human will have an eye-to-foot reaction time 12 times shorter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question asks "*what adaptions are needed*", rather than the more obvious "*Earth is filled with small animals who aren't dead, Why is that?*"

L.Dutch has answered part of this, which is that small things have less to worry about when it comes to falling, but there's a second factor... reaction times, which you're calling $r$.

The time it takes your body to react to some stimulus is bounded by [nerve conduction velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_conduction_velocity). Nerves have a limited speed at which they can conduct a stimulus up to the brain (or the synapses that form part of a [reflex arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex_arc)) and so the larger an animal is the more they suffer from signals just taking too long to get from one end to another in time to respond in a useful fashion.

Something that's one twelfth the size of a human will, all else being equal, be able to respond to a stimulus twelve times faster.

Even without taking into account how much less they weigh (and weight will decrease supralinearly with size) you can see that they have far less to worry about than we do.

Comment: Isn't the "I am falling" alarm produced from the labyrinth in the inner ear?

Comment: @L.Dutch sure, but the "_stop my fall with something other than my face_" action requires communicating with all sorts of heavy, distant, disinterested bits of meat.

Comment: @L.Dutch: Generally, the point is to avoid falling.  Signals from the inner ear get to muscles faster.  Also, a lot is done with proprioception: nerves sense the positions of and forces on muscles and correct them, often without actually going all the way through the brain.  E.g. the way a doctor tests your reflexes by tapping a knee.  Indeed, if you've ever had an ear infection, you may have noticed that you can get around fairly well without those inner ear signals.

Answer (score 6):

You are worrying for nothing.

I have seen 4 nieces learning to walk, with all the related falls. Infants don't have the fast reaction time of an adult, nor the adult's motor coordination, yet they manage to survive falls during their learning phase, as it is proved by the fact we are not extinct.

How is it possible? With smaller bodies comes also a lower mass, and the risk related to a fall is proportional to the involved energy. In a gravitational field the potential energy is $P=mgh$, so if you have a smaller mass falling from a smaller height you have an overall lower energy involved in the impact.

To throw in some numbers:

- an adult man, 190 cm tall and weighing 90 kg would have a fall energy of about $190/2*90*10=85500 J$
- a 2 years old boy, 85 cm tall and weighing 12 kg would have a fall energy of about $85/2*12*10=5100 J$

The 2 years old has 16 times less energy to worry about.

Same reasoning applies to your humanoid: there is a lower inherent risk in the fall, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I'd like to extend : Experiments were made to check how ants react to falls. None suffered any damage from 30+ meters fall. It was partly due to air-resistance, but also reduced energy at the point of impact, too.

Comment: @Tortliena [Stoke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law#Terminal_velocity_of_sphere_falling_in_a_fluid) - terminal velocity goes down with the *square* of the size. A humanoid small enough will never fall, will just be thrown around by the Brownian motion :)

Comment: I like how the back-of-napkin computation assumes the center of mass gets straight on the ground at the end of the fall - applicable to slimy humanoids that reach a pancake state when falling :) Subtracting the half-thickness of the body from the fall height makes for an even more dramatic difference, a child being closer to a ball than a normal adult (umm... maybe there's an advantage being obese)

Comment: Note: size/mass/energy rules do not tell the whole story, across species. Certain small ones, like hedgehog, hamster or rabbit dropped from 4 meters will probably die of internal hemmerage. A cat, or a human, survives. Insects (ants) are protected by six legs and an exoskeleton. Consider mammals, these are straws of bone with meat and muscle draped around it, much more vulnerable for impact damage. But even with mammals, It depends on the species habits. Apes and cats are used to trees, breaking a fall is instinct. Our only handicap is being bipedal, else we would be as good as cats.